# trouble finding python's standerd library's in the file system

Tags: python, linux, module, filesystems

I do understand that I can find the installed library's in "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages".

As in my case though I want to find the standard library's like (os, math, time)
I would just like to find where the default preinstalled modules are located in the linux file system.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
import os
print(os.__file__)
```

you can of course do this with any library